# How do I select a specific element with ID in the DOM and then skip to the next one with the same ID using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

One of the event handlers creates a configuration in which two divs have the same ID in the DOM.

now using the JQuery I want to access the div with the mentioned ID that is placed second in the DOM.

So I am looking for something highly specific $('#theMentionedId').nextWithTheSameId()...

First I am targeting the element with the specified id $('theID');

and now how can I skip to the next element with the same ID in the DOM?

I know that there are different approaches and solutions to this, but I am looking for the method that I described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use classes instead of non-unique unique id's. Unique id's are meant to be used only once, whereas classes can be used as much as you want.

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   <sub>http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute</sub>

---

However, if you cannot change the bad code and you must select the second element with the same id, use jQuery's [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). It uses 0-index style indexes, so the second element will have an index of one.

```
$('[id="YourIdHere"]').eq(1); // Select second element matching #YourIdHere
```

Comment: Yep, driving down a freeway the wrong way might also work sometimes but eventually you will be unhappy with your decision.